# Initialising an array of structures

Tags: c

I tried a sample program to intialise an array of structures as below and was getting an error. But when I intialise the same with a single variable I dont get any.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct s_{
        int a;
        int b;
}s;

typedef struct t_{
        int c;
        int d;
}t;

typedef struct st_{
        s s1;
        t t1;
}st;

#define ST_ALLOC {{20,20},{10,10}}

int main(){
 st str[2] = ST_ALLOC;
 //str[0] = ST_ALLOC;
 //str[1] = ST_ALLOC;

 printf("\n st.s1.a : %d st.t1.d : %d \n",str[1].s1.a,str[1].t1.d);
 return 0;
}
```

error :

> ```
> a.c: In function ‘main’:
> a.c:22: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
> a.c:23: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
> ```

I could not understand why is it so .

Comment: This code compiles for me.  Are you sure that what is here is what you're trying to compile?

Comment: This code is compiling for me as well.

Comment: Check out your code without any modification working: http://ideone.com/VL9RJ0

Comment: Maybe you talk about compilation error in the commented code? (of course when it's not in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your compilation error is in the commented lines, and you've got this message from the compiler when they were not in a comment.

I can see that you've tried to instantiate an array of length 2, that each cell of it will contain the st struct that you've defined in the previous macro. For this purpose you can simply do:

```
st str[2] = {ST_ALLOC,ST_ALLOC};
```

Now it compiles and the running output is:

```
st.s1.a : 20 st.t1.d : 10
```

Answer (score 1):

i get only some compiler warnings

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:25:2: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
test2.c:25:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘str[0].s1’) [-Wmissing-braces]
```

you get the warnings because you only initialize 1 of the 2 structs you declared.

because you are only printing `str[1]`, I suppose you want to initialize `str[0]` to `0`, therefore you have to change the define to:

```
#define ST_ALLOC {{{0,0},{0,0}},{{20,20},{10,10}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The curly-bracket notation is for initializing arrays and can't be used after the definition line.  This is really why the compilation error existed in the lines commented out.

As Mickey pointed out, the issue is a little confused by the misleading intialization. If you wanted to initialize both `st` in an array of two `st` you should use `{ST_ALLOC, ST_ALLOC}`.  If it were just one `st`, this would initialize all elements:

```
st str = ST_ALLOC;
```